# when signin to Apps store very 1st time to download app, it will asking for review

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, itunes-app

I am new in app store.. when trying to download any app it displaying an alert msg" this apple id has not yet been used in itunes stores" review your account information....
so it is neccessary & safe to enter all our credit or debit card information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Apple requires some kind of billing information in order to use an Apple ID in the AppStore.

You can work around this by "buying" a free app first, then you will have the option not to add any payment method so you can go with gift cards only.

But normally (unless your device is infected which is unlikely), it's safe to add this information (as safe as it can be)

Comment: thanks for answerd..so after enterd all d details,i will be charged or its free...?    someone said it wil b charged 1$..den after make download..

Comment: No, normally you shouldn't be charged unless you download something you have to pay for.

Comment: bt for downloading free apps y i should pay..